# How to fix dylint warning "return a type that includes relevant context"?

Tags: rust, error-handling, rust-cargo, linter

I have a function that looks as follows:

```
pub fn hello() -> ResultGeneric<(), ProgramError> {
  // function body...
  some_byte_array.serialize(&mut &mut some_binary_data.borrow_mut()[start..end])?;
}
```

I enabled a linter ([Dylint](https://github.com/trailofbits/dylint)) and now it complains about lines similar to this one.

```
warning: returning a `std::io::Result` could discard relevant context (e.g., files or paths involved)
--> src/mod.rs:50:5
|
50 | |         some_byte_array.serialize(&mut &mut some_binary_data.borrow_mut()[start..end])?;
|  |_________________________________________________________________________________________^
|
= help: return a type that includes relevant context
```

As I understand, the issue here is that `serialize()` would return `Result<T, Error>`, but the code expects `ProgramError`. But I don't understand what I am supposed to do to fix it.

**Question:** How to return a result with relevant context?

Comment: Probably, don't return an error that's just a unit struct, but one with relevant context, what constitues 'relevant context' only you can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind the lint is that returning the error as-is doesn't provide that much information on what went wrong.

`std::io::Error` doesn't contain that much information, for example it can contain [`NotFound`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/enum.ErrorKind.html#variant.NotFound) but won't tell you which file wasn't found.

To fix this, you'd construct a new error that contains relevant information:

```rs
some_byte_array
    .serialize(&mut &mut some_binary_data.borrow_mut()[start..end])
    .map_err(|err| ProgramError::some_constructor("some_byte_array failed to serialize from some_binary_data", err))?;
```

If `ProgramError` isn't your type, hopefully it has a way to either include another error inside it, or add information to it somehow. If it is your type, consider making a variant for this situation so that you can match it if necessary.